# Drupal 7.23 warning and error messages when open page

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Drupal 7.23 When I open page (as anonymous user), I periodically get warning and error messages. The duplicate of header logo appears in the end  of page, right above error messages.
I can't understand conditions when appears this warning & error, but it seems it appears when I open page as anonymous user. Then after logging in, logging out, no any errors shown anymore.

warning:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/ztiw7851207/public_html/includes/common.inc:2700) in
>   drupal_send_headers() (line 1220 of
>   /home/ztiw7851207/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc).
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/ztiw7851207/public_html/includes/common.inc:2700) in
>   drupal_send_headers() (line 1216 of
>   /home/ztiw7851207/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc).

error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062
>   Duplicate entry '' for key 'title': INSERT INTO {aggregator_feed}
>   (fid, url, link, description, image, hash, etag, modified) VALUES
>   (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7); Array (
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 9 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] =>
>   http://hitech.com/rss/reviews/ [:db_insert_placeholder_2] =>
>   http://hitech.com/reviews/ [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => News, reviews
>   and opinion outlet with obsessive coverage of cutting edge gadgets,
>   consumer electronics and the science and technology they're built
>   upon. [:db_insert_placeholder_4] =>
>   http://hitech.com/img/rss_cover.png [:db_insert_placeholder_5] =>
>   1d37c01e3b1346cc3ac3dbf1280c3fd236c3f3433e1d44a4902066a9f3d87cbe
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 0 ) in
>   aggregator_refresh() (line 640 of
>   /home/ztiw7851207/public_html/modules/aggregator/aggregator.module).

How to solve this issues?

Comment: Write some comments about the site setup - which modules are you using, is it a live site, did you experience such problems before, do you have any custom modules etc.

Comment: Custom modules enabled: Adsense module, Chaos tools, Field Slideshow, Field collection, Colorbox, CSS injector, Entity API, Libraries, Views, Views UI, Advanced help. Error PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000] encountered also in previous Drupal versions, too. Warning 'Cannot modify header information' is a new issue. Live [site](http://ow.ly/o3cJc).

Answer (score 1):

Issue may be due to the aggregator_feed module try to uninstall and re install it, if you are using Drush

drush dis aggregator_feed && drush en aggregator_feed

Comment: I removed all items, disabled and uninstalled Feed aggregator module,  then reinstalled it. I have also Feeds module, but its disabled. My guess is that aboved warning and error has to be somehow related with cookies or session expiring. I keep getting an PDOException when trying run cron. `PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key..`  This might be due to the fact I am unable to delete feed items of the old feed. How to clean from database this old feed items?

Comment: I find solution myself. In phpMyAdmin: 1) deleting the problem feed from the aggregator_feed table; 2) deleting all aggregator% entries from the Queue table; 3) running cron to verify that the problem had gone.